# How to make dropdown take available width in input group?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

I have a row with 2 cols, the first one containing a title and the second one containing an input group.

The input group has an icon and a dropdown. My problem is that the dropdown doesn't take the available width (while a select for example does).

**jsfiddle**: https://jsfiddle.net/326qay2p/1/

**Code**:

```
<div class="container-fluid limited">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-8 col-xl-9 col-sm-12 d-flex align-items-center bg-info">
      <h4 class="font-weight-bold d-inline mb-0"></h4>
      <small class="text-muted ml-1">(0)</small>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4 col-xl-3 col-sm-12 bg-danger">
      <div class="input-group">
        <div class="input-group-prepend">
          <span class="input-group-text" id="basic-addon1"><i class="fas fa-sort-amount-down"></i></span>
        </div>
        <div class="dropdown">
          <button class="btn dropdown-toggle" href="#" type="button" id="dropdownMenuLink" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
            Dropdown link
          </button>
          <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenuLink">
            <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a>
            <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a>
            <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I want the inputgroup containing the dropdown to take all the available width in the column. I tried playing with the width but it messes up everything..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can make the `dropdown` occupies the whole width of its parent without using `custom CSS`.

Upgrade to Bootstrap `4.1.1`, if you do not not use it already. Then, add the `flex-grow-1` class to `dropdown` element and the `w-100` to `dropdown-toggle` element.

By default, the text is at the center. But if you want to align it on the left or right side, use `text-left` or `text-right` after `w-100`. Visit this [link](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/utilities/text/), for more info

#### Step 1

```html
<div class="dropdown flex-grow-1">
```

#### Step 2

```html
<button class="btn dropdown-toggle w-100 text-left" href="#" type="button" id="dropdownMenuLink" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.0.12/css/all.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="container-fluid limited">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-8 col-xl-9 col-sm-12 d-flex align-items-center bg-info">
      <h4 class="font-weight-bold d-inline mb-0"></h4>
      <small class="text-muted ml-1">(0)</small>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4 col-xl-3 col-sm-12 bg-danger">
      <div class="input-group">
        <div class="input-group-prepend">
          <span class="input-group-text" id="basic-addon1"><i class="fas fa-sort-amount-down"></i></span>
        </div>
        <div class="dropdown flex-grow-1">
          <button class="btn dropdown-toggle w-100 text-left" href="#" type="button" id="dropdownMenuLink" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
            Dropdown link
          </button>
          <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenuLink">
            <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a>
            <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a>
            <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Check [full-width-dropdown](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/vjWJPB)  on Codepen

Comment: How can we then aligh the text in the button to the left or right (with the arrow)? because it looks weird irght now :/

Comment: @Haytam Use `text-left` after `w-100` to align left. Updated all of the codes

Comment: THank you, I used `text-right` as its more appealing!